# VB6 To send a Form Post

Tags: vb6, form-post

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim httpReq As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim strLineOut As String
Dim strReturn As String
Dim strStatus As String

lblResponse1.Caption = ""
DoEvents
strLineOut = "<form name=""form1"" method=""post"" enctype=""multipart/form-data"">" & vbCrLf
strLineOut = strLineOut & "  <input name=""hdntype"" type=""hidden"" id=""hnd1"" value=""1"">" & vbCrLf
strLineOut = strLineOut & "  <input name=""hnd1"" type=""hidden"" id=""hnd1"" value=""Value1"">" & vbCrLf
strLineOut = strLineOut & "  <input name=""hdn2"" type=""hidden"" id=""hdn2"" value=""Value2"">" & vbCrLf
strLineOut = strLineOut & "  <input type=""submit"" name=""Submit"" value=""Submit"">" & vbCrLf
strLineOut = strLineOut & "</form>" & vbCrLf

httpReq.Open "POST", "http://www.XXXX.com/XMLProjects/vb6test/form_post.asp", False
httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
'text/xml
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded
'httpReq.StatusText
'httpReq.Status
'httpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strLineOut)
httpReq.Send (strLineOut)
strStatus = httpReq.StatusText
strReturn = httpReq.ResponseText
Debug.Print strReturn & vbCrLf & strStatus
lblResponse1.Caption = strReturn & vbCrLf & strStatus
Set httpReq = Nothing
```

The asp that catches the form cannot seem to recognize the form.  It sees a form with one item.
The catch code in the asp is:

```
Response.Write Request.Form("hdntype") 
Response.Write "the form object is " & Request.Form.Item(1) & vbCrLf
```

The response from the asp is:

```
the form object is "form1"method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
<inputname="hdntype"type="hidden"id="hnd1"value="1">
<inputname="hnd1"type="hidden"id="hnd1"value="Nick">
<inputname="hdn2"type="hidden"id="hdn2"value="Arnone">
<inputtype="submit"name="Submit"value="Submit"></form>
```

It does not see the item hdntype, or any other item within the form. It sees 1 item, the entire form.

If I do a Request.TotalBytes, I can see everythinhg in the asp.
If I add a querystring objects, I can see each object. 
I cannot see form objects.

Comment: Did you paste the response EXACTLY as it was output? It seems to be completely missing spaces as shown. It's also missing the opening `<` character for the form.

Comment: Why are you sending HTML to the server?  That isn't how a form post works.

Comment: @Bob77 Ha. Good point. I got so caught up in looking at the response, that I never really looked at the request.

Comment: I do not want to use XML on this project.  Should this work?

Comment: I want to exchange information between the server and a program running at a customer’s location.
This there a better way? I am open to ideas. The program needs to assess the server with just about every action. I need a communication system that is fast as the server will be accessing a SQL server and sending back the information.  I do not want to use XML due to the character constraints.  
The other method I am looking at is using delimited text files back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6, if you send the data like this:

```
strIDJob = "34"
strAuthString = "supertest"

DataToPost = ""
DataToPost = DataToPost & "IDJob=" & strIDJob & "&"
DataToPost = DataToPost & "AUTH=" & strAuthString & "&"
```

(im sending it to an ASP page, using the CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0") component)

(sending with POST with only this header included: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Then, you can retrieve each item using the code bellow (in ASP), one by one:

```
IDJob = Request.Form.Item(1)   'here is the core point of this post. This is the line that matters
AUTH = Request.Form.Item(2)   'here is the core point of this post. This is the line that matters

response.write "IDJob = " & IDJob & "<BR>"
response.write "AUTH = " & AUTH & "<BR>"
Response.End
```

this code in asp produces the following return/output:

IDJob = 34
AUTH = supertest